# Should I store a database backup used for our automated tests in git?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

We are currently trying to add automated integration tests to our continuous integration (CI) process. Our CI process is using TeamCity, and already builds our .NET solution, runs NUnit tests and deploys via Octopus Deploy. It is a typical web application and uses a SQL Server database.

All of the code and unit tests are in a Git repo.

Now, the automated tests have been written in TestComplete and work great. The tests rely on specific data to be present in the database before the tests are run, so I'm planning on the CI process restoring a database before running the tests.

I'm almost positive that these automated tests belong in the same repo as the code - after all the tests should be versioned along with the code. What I'm not so sure about is the database backup. I think it's important that we know which database backup was used for each version of the tests, but I've read that it's not a great idea to store large binary files in Git. The backup at the moment is 40mb.

I'm torn between storing the backup in Git and just storing it on a file share somewhere. I'm just worried that the database backup could get overwritten in the future and previous versions on our tests would then fail. I guess it's not common to want to run automated tests for a previous build though, so maybe it's not an issue and I'm worrying unnecessarily. Has anyone else encountered a similar situation? And what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been in the same situation, but here's how I would solve this:

- The test should go into the same repo as the code. If that's not possible, put them in a different repo, but make sure to keep the versions in sync, so you know which set of tests works for the version of the code.
- Put the database backup file on a file share. Use a directory with a version number or a timestamp so you can keep multiple versions of the backup. For example `backup-2015-02-26`.
- In your code base, add a file that points to the database backup as a reference. Commit and versionize that file with your code base. This way, you will always know with database backup file works with a specific version of the code.
- Only delete database backup files that you absolutely don't need anymore.
- Make sure that the file share that holds your database backup files is part of a daily/weekly/incremental backup plan.

Adding the database backup file to your code base will simply bloat it for everyone, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I completely overlooked versioning the backup by using filenames! I added the filename in the test scripts, so we know which backup was used. Simple, and keeps the large files out of git. Perfect.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear that it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding too much data in git repository might lead to big repo size, which might lead to lost productivity and high onboarding time for new developers.

You will be better off storing data in cloud services like s3 if you CI env can access internet. If not, there aren't much option except storing these files on intranet accessible from CI env and developer's local machines.